# Java метод не изменяет передаваемый объект

Tags: java, дата, объекты

Объясните пожалуйста, почему не меняется b.

```
public static void Vvod(Date date){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    System.out.println("viberite deistvie:");
    System.out.println("1:ne vvoditi date = null");
    System.out.println("2:vvesti datu v formate dd.MM.yyyy");
    int vibor = in.nextInt();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    Date date1 = new Date();
    date = date1;
    switch (vibor) {
        case 1: {
           date1 = null;
            System.out.println("date =null");
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                try {
                   date1 = sdf.parse(br.readLine());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
   Date b = null;
   Peresecenie.Vvod(b);
   //так и остался null
}
```

Comment: а почему должна меняться `b`?

Comment: я хочу, что бы оно поменялось, но не совсем понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы метод поменять объект

Comment: [Can I pass parameters by reference in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1068760/2881286)

Answer (score 2):

Ты передаешь в метод копию ссылки объекта **b**, в методе переменной **date** присваивается данная ссылка. После чего ты меняешь ссылку, хранящуюся в **date**, на другую ссылку. Следовательно в теле метода ты теряешь ссылку на объект, который тебе пришел. Иначе говоря, ты не меняешь объект, а заменяешь ссылку, хранящуюся в локальной переменной.

Если ты хочешь поменять содержимое объекта, то ты должен вызвать у него соответствующие методы.

Comment: Да, но только Date immutable

Answer (score 1):

Полностью согласен с выше написанным. Если вы хотите изменить его, то сделайте возвращаемый тип метода Date при вызове переприсваивайте переменную b на то, что вернул метод:

public class Application {

```
public static Date Vvod(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    System.out.println("viberite deistvie:");
    System.out.println("1:ne vvoditi date = null");
    System.out.println("2:vvesti datu v formate dd.MM.yyyy");
    int vibor = in.nextInt();
    BufferedReader br;
    Date date = new Date();
    switch (vibor) {
        case 1: {
            date = null;
            System.out.println("date =null");
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try {
                date = sdf.parse(br.readLine());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return date;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Date b = Application.Vvod();
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

}